# How to automate the build of a very large project?

Tags: build, cmake, build-process

I am working on a legacy project that consists of an excessive number of modules (over 900).
I am trying to build a particular EXE, and it needs a whooping 322 DLLs! (according to Dependency Walker)

The existing build system consists of:

- All of the EXEs, DLLs and LIBs, already prebuilt;
- All the headers dumped together in one INCLUDE directory;
- Separated makefiles for each project, with no dependency tracking.

Normally, my colleagues would consider this just an annoyance and not a real problem.

Problem is, we are using a very old C compiler, and the debugger doesn't work properly on newer versions of Windows (not to mention it's not very user friendly). So, I want to rebuild everything with Visual Studio 2013.

I have already created a number of CMake build scripts, with some success – in three weeks, I have managed to build some 100 DLLs. The only problem is that I had to create all the build scripts by hand.

The question is: how could I speed up the process? Are there any tools/techniques that I could use?

Comment: You are probably stuck with your current approach. Setting up a working build environment for a project of such scale is a highly non-trivial task. While there are some tools out there that attempt to automate migration to CMake, those stop working quite quickly once the codebase exceeds toy-project size.